# I can't seem to get this hat on straight!

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

I carefully positioned my hat to fit my head just right:

[image: Hat editor]

But it seems to be shifted to the left a few pixels elsewhere (same in Firefox and Chrome):

[image: SO answer card]

<sup>Stack Overfow</sup>

[image: Skeptics answer card]

<sup>Skeptics</sup>

The top bar is also affected on some sites:

[image: SO top bar]

<sup>Stack Overfow</sup>

[image: Meta SE top bar]

<sup>Meta SE</sup>

[image: InfoSec top bar]

<sup>InfoSec</sup>

However, it is in the correct position in the top bar on some sites somehow:

[image: Skeptics top bar]

<sup>Skeptics</sup>

[image: Bricks top bar]

<sup>Bricks</sup>

It's not a huge deal of course, it just bothers perfectionists like me.

Comment: Maybe the hat is in the right position and your head is a few pixels off ...

Comment: @rene :D I guess according to Einstein, whether the hat is off by a few pixel, or the head is off by a few pixels, depends upon your frame of reference.

Comment: It looks fine to me in your usercard here on this question.  Does it to you?

Comment: @MonicaCellio No, still looks off.

Comment: Alexander, on this webpage (your Profile) it's clearly off to the left a couple of pixels: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278148/alexander-omara , as it is in the avatar shown above. Firefox 58.0 Android.