# Hats on top bar profile not aligned properly

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash

I spent a bit of time aligning my hat, but every time I glanced at the top bar it looked off, well either way, it seems to be a pixel or so off to the right.

[image]

Comment: Maybe, maybe not duplicate: [I can't seem to get this hat on straight!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304501/307988)